# How can I add and remove some css from a span with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
container.removeClass("ui-state-error-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-alert");
container.addClass("ui-state-error-icon").addClass("ui-icon-alert");
```

Is there a simple way that I can also add and remove the following CSS?

```
display: inline-block;
```

I looked at the jQuery documentation and found this:

```
$(this).css("color","red");
```

But how would I remove the display parameter?

Thanks

Comment: what do u mean by remove the display parameter, make `display:none` or remove it

Comment: Easy way, you sould put your CSS properties into a class :)

Comment: well if I add it with something like container.css("display","inline-block") then how do I take it away. I don't see an addCss / deleteCSS option in jQuery.

Comment: I just didn't really want to keep having more and more classes. This is just a one off situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know you can pass several classnames in [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) like this, separated by whitespace:

```
 container.removeClass("ui-state-error-icon ui-icon-alert");
 container.addClass("ui-state-error-icon ui-icon-alert"");
```

To change the "display" css rule, use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) as you saw in the doc.

<del>Now you cannot exactly add or remove the css rule, you have to replace the value of "display" by something else, and it depends on what you want to achieve:</del>

You can set the value to empty string to remove the *inline* css rule. As @nnnnnn stated, the value of "display" will then be  - either the one defined in a remaining css class applied to the element - or the default value of "display" for the type of element.

```
container.css('display', '');
```

Values of the rule "display" - [display (css property)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display)

[Inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Inline_elements)

[Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Comment: You can set it to an empty string. Then the element will pick up whatever `display` setting cascades through from the stylesheet (in the case of inheritable properties this might be from the containing element). If there is no setting that applies in the style sheet setting it to empty string should cause the default for the element type (e.g., inline for anchors and block for divs) to apply.

Answer (score 3):

just make it empty jquery will remove the parametre

```
$(this).css("display","");
```